# How do I manually install older versions of unity (2019) for Linux (Arch)

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, version, archlinux, manual

I am aware of this page: https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive but the downloads are only for windows and mac and despite having it installed, the "unity hub" button does nothing. I have found places to download even older versions like 2018 but I need version "2019.2.5f1". Can I download and use the mac version? Is there somewhere I can download this compiled for Linux without using unity hub? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Interestingly https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/2019.2.5 only mentions windows and mac versions

Comment: Yeah this is my issue. There must be somewhere to download specific versions for offline installation right?

Comment: Well there were links on a unity forum, but they stop at 2019.1 .. and so havent been updated since april last year

Comment: again yeah I found these but I require a specific 2019 version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The UnityHub link will have a version hash in it which is unique across platforms. With that hash, you can build the Linux version download URL yourself.

In your case, you need 2019.2.5f1, which gives you the UnityHub link unityhub://2019.2.5f1/9dace1eed4cc

You can download the tarball at the following URL:

https://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/9dace1eed4cc/LinuxEditorInstaller/Unity.tar.xz

The [`unity-editor`](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=unity-editor) package is a good one to modify the PKGBUILD file for if you'd like to install an arbitrary version as a proper package.

1. Clone the project
2. Tweak the PKGBUILD version and hash to the one you want
3. Run `makepkg -g` to generate the checksum for the new tarball
4. Insert the new checksum into the PKGBUILD
5. Run `makepkg -p PKGBUILD` to compile the package
6. Run `sudo pacman -U ./unity-editor-${pkgversion}.pkg.tar` to install your newly built package.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will try this later

Comment: How do I get the version hash? Let's say I need 2019.3.0b6

Comment: You can get version hashes from the links in the Unity Download Archive. https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive If it's not there, I'm not sure how to find it.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is having this issue and want to download older versions from unityhub, there is solution that worked for me :

1. Go to unity download archive
2. Copy redirection link from the green button (you can right click it and select "Open Link in new tab", and then copy it from here)
3. Once you have the link, open up your terminal and go to location in which you have UnityHub.AppImage
4. Simply use this command : `./UnityHub.AppImage link` where link is what you copied (for example `./UnityHub.AppImage unityhub://2019.3.13f1/d4ddf0d95db9` to download 2019.3.13 version of uinity)

Answer (score 0):

I have two of the hashes:

- 89d6087839c2    [Unity 2019.3.1f1](https://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/89d6087839c2/LinuxEditorInstaller/Unity.tar.xz)
- b9898e2d04a4 [unity 2019.2.16f1](https://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/b9898e2d04a4/LinuxEditorInstaller/Unity.tar.xz)

Comment: to get the release ID from version number see https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive ([via](https://www.gamingonlinux.com/wiki/Unity_Games_Working_On_Linux_(User_Ported)))